# Can I change the Wordpress default color?

Tags: themes

I just installed Wordpress and am struggling to change the default color. Currently, my default color is "pink" because I have the Wordpress 2020 theme. However, I would like to change it to black.

I'm mainly interested in chaning the colors of my menu navigation.

When clicking on the color customization menu, I have the option to select between Default and Custom.For some reason, I cannot pick black as a custom color.

Any tips on how to change my default color?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in the wrong area... ...those are background colours for the theme, what you're looking for is the Additional CSS at the bottom of the customizer.  (Screenshots below.)

In the Additional CSS you'll have a text area where you can put your own CSS, use this:

```
body:not(.overlay-header) .primary-menu > li > a, body:not(.overlay-header) .primary-menu > li > .icon, .modal-menu a, .footer-menu a, .footer-widgets a, #site-footer .wp-block-button.is-style-outline, .wp-block-pullquote:before, .singular:not(.overlay-header) .entry-header a, .archive-header a, .header-footer-group .color-accent, .header-footer-group .color-accent-hover:hover{
    color:#000;
}
```

That'll set all of the menu items that are currently pink to be black.

[image: Additional CSS in Customizer]

[image: The CSS rules]